# Links on second line don't show up properly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, hyperlinks, chat

To reproduce:

1. Start typing a message.
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to create a new line in the same message.
3. Type a link on this line (e.g. `[foo](http://example.com)`)
4. Send the message.
5. You will notice that the message appears as `[foo](http://example.com)` instead of appearing as `foo` with the text linked.

Here's an example: http://chat.webapps.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/907#907

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It assumes multi-line posts are pastes (from arbitrary sources), so markdown rules don't apply. This is by design.

Just send multiple messages, or don't use fragmented sentences.